# Reading in, breaking a data frame in pieces, and running operations using for loop in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a data frame of 6 million data entries and 28 columns in a .csv file (lets call it `rd.csv`)thats far too big for my computer to handle. Im trying to read it in pieces of manageable sizes of one million entries, and run different analysis on it. At first I was doing it by simply specifying  each function call for each piece of the original data frame but obviously it's better to do it based on an algorithm.

I'm using a `for` loop but the thing is that it only saves the last element of the loop to my global enviroment. So, it only saves the sixth iteration. Here's the code:

```
for(i in 3){
nam <- paste("cd", i, sep = "")
if(i == 1){
  assign(nam, read.csv("rd.csv", header = TRUE, nrows = 1000000))
  a <- sapply(nam, class)
  b <- names(nam)
  ##Stats functions here
  rm(nam)
  }
  else{
  assign(nam, read.csv("rd.csv", colClasses = a, col.names = b, nrows = 1000000, skip = i*1000000))
  ##Stats functions here
  rm(nam)
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me with the the part of saving each variable created after an iteration?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to save, but you have to define your storage outside of the loop and then add/assign/append your newly calculated results onto your data struture.  In the class above a and b are rewritten on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: The idea is that when the for loops starts, it creates a variable through "nam" call cdi. The if function check whether i is 1; if so, it assigns to the cd1 (through the first iteration of nam) the first 1 million data entries of the file, and later checks for class of column and names that will be used in later iterations of the for loop. The idea is to have 6 data frames with one million entries by the end of the loop.

So you are sayin that I should try something like creating the variables cd1...cd6 outside of the for loop? As in, creating empty data frames?

Comment: So there are lots of much better ways of approaching this, but I'm still struggling to understand what specifically the performance bottleneck is. Your comment says that at the end you plan on having the equivalent of the full data set in memory, but your question/code sort of implies that you feel it necessary to operate in chunks and only keep the _results_ which would presumably be much, much smaller than each chunk.

Comment: I will later add more stats functions to the loop and remove each individual data frame originally read in so my computer can handle it. So, essentially I will only keep the data which has analysis of the original. You mentioned you have other ways of doing this, how would you face this?

Comment: This is the straight forward way and the not the best.  You are correct from your previous comment create 6 empty arrays/matrixes/dataframes outside the loop to store the result of your statistical calculations.  Once the calculation is complete store the result, delete the original data, and read the next group in.  At the end of the loop you will have all of your results which you could then combine for additional analysis/presentation.

Comment: First, forget that you ever heard of the function `assign`. It will only get you into trouble; don't use it until you are _absolutely_ sure it's the only option. Keep the data in a local SQLite database and read the data in chunks either directly using **RSQLite** or **dplyr**, operate on each chunk, etc. Structure the loop so that there is only _one_ object with data that is created at the start of the loop, and removed at the end. None of this `cd1`, `cd2`, junk.